# Ubuntu could not detect wifi interface

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, 20.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 recently. My wifi requires special driver as the builtin rt2800pci driver don't work. So, I downloaded the driver from [GitHub](https://github.com/Borwe/rt3290-linux-drivers). On 18.04, the system used to load the driver every boot. I used to issue this command boot every boot, `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` so the system could recognize the wifi interface. Without this, `iwconfig` used to recognize the interface but settings could not detect the interface. Now after upgrading, settings could not detect the wifi interface. But `iwconfig` can easily recognize it. How can I fix it?

Update:

I issued `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info` on terminal, and this is the content of wireless-info.txt:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gfKH9HxPNQ/

Comment: Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: @chili555 I have included the output.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make two changes. First, the package ndiswrapper will not properly drive your wireless device, or any that I am aware of, in any recent; that is, not end-of-life Ubuntu version. Let's remove it:

```
sudo apt purge ndiswrapper*
```

And remove it from /etc/modules:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Edit the file so that it only contains:

```
rtl8188fu
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x).

Next, we'll make a change in Network Manager:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Change the line managed=false to managed=true. Save and close nano as above. Reboot.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that I have problem with the RT3290 adapter. The buggy driver is rt3290.

Comment: I have updated wireless-info.

Comment: Where is the updated wireless info? It looks just the same.

Comment: Is it same? The first one was without loading the the buggy driver rt3290sta and activating the buggy wireless interface ra0, and the current one is after doing that. I have already removed ndiswrapper and managed=true is already set at NetworkManager.conf by default.

Comment: I don't understand. Is it your goal to use the internal device with the buggy driver rt3290sta or the USB that seems to be working correctly? I recommend that we concentrate on one or the other; not both.

Comment: I want to use the internal device with buggy driver rt3290sta and buggy interface.

Comment: The paste you have above still shows managed=false and ndiswrapper. Again, where is the updated wireless info? If we are trying to get the buggy internal device working properly, please remove the USB, reboot, run the wireless script, paste it and then give us the link.

Comment: I have updated wireless-info again. And this time I read it and see that it shows `managed=true` and there is no ndiswrapper.